# Teradata - selecting between two columns based on whether it starts with a number or not

Tags: sql, case, teradata, case-when

I have the a query which looks similar to:

```
SELECT
  s.cola, s.colb, t.colc, t.cold, u.cole, u.colf, u.colg, u.colh, u.coli, u.colj, u.colk, u.coll 
FROM table1 s
INNER JOIN table2 t
  ON s.colb = t.colc
INNER JOIN table3 u
  ON u.colm = t.cold
WHERE cast(s.cola as date) between date '2017-11-06' and date '2017-11-10'
ORDER BY 3
```

I need to add a new column, called `col_new`, which is to be filled by either `u.colm` or `u.coln`. This column will have values from `u.colm` if that column starts with a number. Otherwise it will have values from `u.coln`. It is known that either `u.coln` or `u.colm` starts with a number, for each entry in table `u`.

I tried the following query to test if entries starting with a number can be identified or not:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(colm), 1, 1)) = 1
        THEN 'yes'
        ELSE 'no'
      END AS col_new
FROM table_u
```

It returned the error:  `Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'substring' keyword.`

Kindly suggest a solution.

**Edit:**
Exact Error:

```
[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'substring' keyword.
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error? Your syntax looks right.

Comment: Also, if it starts with a number, why not try using `LEFT` instead. `ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(colm), 1)) = 1`

Comment: I have added the exact error message from Teradata.

Comment: It gave me the same error, but with `LEFT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `isnumeric()`, just do a comparison:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(colm), 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 'yes'
             ELSE 'no'
        END) AS col_new
FROM table_u;
```

`LEFT()` is a convenient shorthand for the first "n" characters of a string.